# Passing parameters to nunit console tool

Tags: c#, nunit, unit-testing, nunit-console

I would like to know if its possible to send parameters via nunit console app and then use the parameters to do the testing.

This is the test method I have:

```
namespace MyUnitTest.Tests
{
    public class QuestsTests
    {
        [TestFixture]
        public class QuestionsTests
        {
            public void CountQuestions(int ID, int expectedCount)
            {
                var ops = new Ops(siteID);

                var questCount = ops.GetSurveyQuestionsCount();

                Assert.That(questCount, Is.EqualTo(expectedCount));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I want to run the tests via console, this is how the command is set at this time:

[image]

What are my options now for submitting parameters to the test fixture?

Comment: in the `IDE` under the properties of your project, are you aware that you can setup parameters there..?

Comment: @MethodMan yes but I need a way to send parameters from the command line, because multiple people will need to do the testing for multiple tests, and we can't change the parameters in the properties of the project. Thanks for your help